# Dict sorter returns dict of lists

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I've created a function to sort dicts:

```
def dict_sort(dic):
  new_dic = {}
  items = list(dic.items())
  sorted_dic = items.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
  for a,b in items:
    new_dic.setdefault(a, []).append(b)

  return new_dic
```

Using an example dict of `ex = {'A':1, 'B':3, 'C':2}`, this becomes `{'A': [1], 'B': [3], 'C': [2]}`.

It looks like this turns it into a dict of lists. How can I go about removing those lists so that the output is `{'A':1, 'C':2, 'B':3}`?

Comment: Why did you use `new_dic.setdefault(a, []).append(b)` instead of usual item access? This creates the lists.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "usual item access"?

Comment: If not done already you should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python 3.6+ maintains insertion order of a dictionary's items

```
def dict_sort(dic):
  return {a:b for a,b in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])}
```